# Simple question on limit of the modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I know that for real functions, if the limit at infinity of $f$ is a number $l$, then the limit of $|f|$ is $|l|$. Is this true for complex functions too? Thanks.

I'm thinking that if a function vanishes at infinity, then its modulus (distance from origin) also vanishes. And vice-versa. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it is true for every function with values in a normed vector space. This follows from the [reverse triangular inequality](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality)
$$
|\|f(x)\|-\|l\||\leq\|f(x)-l\|.
$$

In other words, the map $y\to \|y\|$ is $1$-Lipschitz, hence continuous.

In particular, if $\lim_{+\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{+\infty}\|f(x)\|=\|\lim_{+\infty}f(x)\|$.

Note: in $\mathbb{C}$, replace $\|\cdot\|$ by $|\cdot|$.